# Windows Phone 7 application question

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to create a website "launcher" application for Windows Phone 7.
Basically, it only has to be an icon in the application list, that opens the webbrowser and loads a url given within the application.

I am completely ignorant about microsoft dev... I'm a php/java developer and had so far nearly succeeded in avoiding any contact with microsoft products/languages... :) So please be kind.

I installed the microsoft dev tools and got the sample "Mini-Browser" from here (bottom of the list):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

This does pretty much exactly what I want, except I dont want a text box and a go button.
I just want to open the browser with a specific url and that's it, then the user can navigate through the site...

I removed the textbox and button, but I can't find a way to load the url (or in this case to call the button1_Click function) automatically, I'm looking for something like "onLoad" in html, for this xaml tag: (line26)

```
<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />
```

So what I want is that when this tag is loaded, it fires the function from MainPage.xaml.cs...

Can someone help?

Comment: What's the point of such an "application"?

Comment: The point is basically to have an icon in the application list that will open a specific website. Kind of a bookmark/shortcut I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MainPage.xaml.cs you can add the following line to the constructor:

```
Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
```

Then in the handler:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MyBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://example.com"));
}
```

You may need to give the browser a name using the `x:Name="MyBrowser"` attribute in the XAML and then you can just say `MyBrowser.Navigate()`...

Answer (score 2):

Check these posts:

[Navigating with the WebBrowser Control on WP7](http://wildermuth.com/2010/12/24/Navigating_with_the_WebBrowser_Control_on_WP7)

[31 Days of Windows Phone | Day #18: WebBrowser Control](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7c-Day-18-WebBrowser-Control.aspx)

You can also try something like this:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
            webBrowserTask.URL = "http://www.http://stackoverflow.com";
            webBrowserTask.Show();
        }
```

Hope this will help you.